# Problems with list-of-figures

Tags: table-of-contents, revtex

I'm having difficulties in displaying list of figures. Does someone know what is the issue? I get  the error message: `Illegal unit of measure (mu inserted)` corresponding to the part of the code before `begin{document}`. Figures are either `.jpeg` or `.pdf`. Here is the part of my code:

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,final]{revtex4}

\usepackage{sidecap}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{slashed} 

\usepackage{lmodern}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand*{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand*{\p@subsection}{}
\renewcommand*{\thesubsubsection}{\thesubsection.\arabic{subsubsection}}
\renewcommand*{\p@subsubsection}{}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\def\ps@myPS{%
    \def\@oddfoot{\null\hfill\thepage}
    \def\@evenfoot{\thepage}%
    \def\@evenhead{\null\hfil\slshape\leftmark}%
    \def\@oddhead{{\slshape\rightmark}}}%
\makeatother

\pagestyle{myPS}
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\graphicspath{ {figures/} }
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum


\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usepackage{caption,tikz}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup{compatibility=false}

\usepackage{sidecap}

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\DeclareCaptionJustification{justified}{\justifying}
\captionsetup{justification=justified,singlelinecheck=false,labelfont=normal}

\usepackage[capitalize]{cleveref}

\raggedbottom
\setlength{\topmargin}{0pt}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathpzc}{OT1}{pzc}{m}{it}

\voffset=-0.6in
\DeclareMathOperator{\Tr}{Tr}

\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={210mm,297mm},
 left=30mm,
 right=30mm,
 top=30mm,
 bottom=30mm,
 }

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\numberwithin{equation}{subsection}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures

 \makeatletter
    \let\toc@pre\relax
  \let\toc@post\relax
    \makeatother

  \newpage

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{AFree}
\caption{{\bf {Caption.} 
\label{afreedom}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome. Why is there so much stuff going one? The revtex people just want content, right? They already have the layout complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class `revtex4` does not support `\listoffigures`. Use the class `revtex4-1` instead.

```
\documentclass{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}
\caption{Caption.} 
\label{afreedom}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Side note:** Your document has *many* problems. You are loading several packages twice, and you have lots of redefinitions that I expect to cause problems. My suggestion: remove everything of which you don't know why it's there (= everything in the preamble?), and only add packages if you actually need an extra feature.